# how to set the values of a timer of an array using fetched data?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, fetch-api

I'm trying to set the value of a timer from a python document, my question is, how can I insert the time for each area after fetching the data?

```
fetch('https://python document/')

.then((data) => data.json())
//
.then((data) =>
console.log(data)
//do I have to pass it on from here to the array below?
)
//
.catch(error =>{
  console.log('does not work!');
})
};

const allAreas = [
  createArea('area-1', whatever we get from the python will set the time here in minutes, ex 60 * 60),
  createArea('area-2', and here ex 10* 60),
  createArea('area-3', and here ex 20 * 60),
  createArea('area-4', and here  ex 30* 60),
  createArea('area-5', and here ex 40* 60),
  createArea('area-6', and here ex 50 * 60),
  createArea('area-7', and here ex 90 * 60),
  createArea('area-12', and here ex 120 * 60), 
];
```

I am unsure about how to pass the values that I get from my fetch request to the array.

please help.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Can you show an example of the data received from the fetch?

Answer (score 1):

This depends quite a lot on the way the data which you are fetching is structured.

It also depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, do you want those values inside of the array to be present at all times?

Do you want this functionality to be preserved accross page reloads or various pages of your website (assuming that you're creating some sort of website)

The simplest way to do this is in this way ->

```
const createArea = function (area, timer) {
console.log(area, timer) // Your logic here...
}

let allAreas = []

fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {allAreas.push(createArea('area-5', (json.price * 60)))})
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, this is for a web application project, basically, it will be displaying data coming from the server that will be updated every 3 to 5 min, we can get values anywhere from 10 to 500 and later will display them to an HTML document, I was just unsure about how to pass on the data one I receive it, I'll give it a go, thanks!